# Is it possible to catch an exception in another .cpp or .h file?

Tags: c++, exception

I am trying to create a program using windows form in c++ and i am wondering if i can throw an exception in logic.cpp and catch it with my ui.cpp

Comment: If you call a function in logic.cpp from ui.cpp, yes you can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can catch an exception that was thrown anywhere down the callstack. If the function in `ui.cpp` calls the function in `logic.cpp` that throws the exception then yes, you can catch it.

Comment: You might also need to import or include the appropriate header file where the exception type is declared.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. But you need to make sure that the respective source files are compiled with the same settings and defines (and likely other things) to make sure that the exception API/ABI doesn't differ between compilation units.